# Terminal command "ls" in AppleScript list

Tags: terminal, applescript

How can I create a list in AppleScript that shows the results of a terminal command.
For example `ls /Applications/`
Every application should be shown in the list, so that I can choose an item from the list.

Comment: Why downvotes? Seems to be a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to run a terminal command to do this.  Applescript can handle it without the need of a terminal command.

```
set myList to {}
tell application "Finder"
    set fileList to name of files of folder "Applications" of startup disk
    repeat with currentFile in fileList
        copy currentFile to the end of myList
    end repeat
end tell
choose from list myList
```

Setting a terminal command to a variable can be done as followed:

```
set myVar to do shell script "ls /Applications"
```

Comment: The OP asks for `ls` as an example. Can all shell commands be invoked like this?

Comment: Can folders be shown too? And how can I change the place with a POSIX path?

Comment: @user121028 Like this:   set fileList to name of files of ((POSIX file "/Applications/Utilities/") as alias)